# How to get branch head commit using stash rest api

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I am having some problem with getting `HEAD` commit from a stash branch.I can get branch commits using following REST call.

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits?until={branch Name}
```

Also i can get HEAD commit in master using  `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/HEAD`

like wise i would like to know that how can i get branch HEAD commit using Stash REST API.

Answer (score 6):

For a branch name without forward slashes below works perfect:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/develop
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/master
```

But this fails when referring to `feature/JIRA-123-foo-bar`-like branches.
Alternatively you could invoke

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/branches
```

which will give you all the branches and their latest commits. See [Stash API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html#idp959232) for more

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking to get a commit message from feature branch, please have a look:-

1. Get the commit id by using

   `` export COMMIT=`curl -s -H 'Authorization: Basic ***************=' --request GET https://bitbucket.your-organisation.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/branches | jq -r '[.values[]."latestCommit"][0]'` ``

   This will give you the latest commit to your repository(you can even limit this for feature branch.
2. Get commit message by using commit id

   `curl -s -H 'Authorization: Basic ***************=' --request GET https://bitbucket.your-organisation.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/$COMMIT | jq .`

   Note: if you are specifically looking to get JIRA id from the commit message, replace 2nd command by following

   `curl -s -H 'Authorization: Basic ***************=' --request GET https://bitbucket.your-organisation.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/$COMMIT | jq  -r '.properties["jira-key"][]'`